# how to display a data table with blank rows using jsf 2.0

Tags: java, datatable, jsf-2, facelets

I'm trying to show a empty datatable with 10 rows on the page load, when i try using the below code, it does not show any rows.

```
<h:dataTable id="d" value="" bgcolor="#9AC8E6" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="10" width="100%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" >
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Student Number" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{10}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Student Name" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Standard" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Marks" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Percentage" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>            
                </h:dataTable>
```

Need help to display a datatable with blank columns and rows

### UPDATE

According to the given solution I tried this way but could not resolve the problem

```
   <h:dataTable id="d" value="#{inquiryBean.blankList}" var="emptyBean" bgcolor="#9AC8E6" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="10" width="100%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" >
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Item Number" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{emptyBean.itemNumber}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Material" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{emptyBean.material}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Description" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{emptyBean.description}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Unit" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{emptyBean.unit}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Quantity" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{emptyBean.quantity}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Delivery Date" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{emptyBean.deliveryDate}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

## Bean Class ##

```
//getters and setters
List blankList = new ArrayList();

public List getBlankList() {
    InquiryBean bean = new InquiryBean();
    bean.setItemNumber("");
    bean.setMaterial("");
    bean.setDescription("");
    bean.setQuantity("");
    bean.setUnit("");
    bean.setDeliveryDate(null);
    return blankList;
}
```

Am i missing something????

Comment: Regarding your update: I don't get it. Your managed bean _inquiryBean_ contains a list of managed beans of the same type? Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the value for the `value` attribute (sorry, no pun intended). It's how you specify rows of the dataTable. The way you have it now it's specifying there should no (null) rows in the output table (if it only works).

That's why my suggestion is to declare some bean which would have a 10-elements collection available as some property (if that's your preference). And have an EL expression pointing to this bean's property in the `value` attribute.

You can take a look at [some examples on Internet](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/46-hdatatable-java-server-faces-jsf.html) (take a look at `DataTableBean` there).

Basically your should:

- define a bean (in `faces-config.xml` if it's a plain JSF)
- define a bean implementation class with a 10-element collection
- point to this collection using EL expression in the  `value` attribute of the `h:dataTable` component.

UPDATE:

Following your update. Now you have a defined what seems a proper bean and its implementing class. However your 'blankList' is an empty collection (as exactly the name indicates). If you want to have 10 rows in the data table you basically need to call `add()` method on your collection 10 times (or something similar).

Comment: thank you for the reply...kindly go through my update and need ur help again

Comment: It worked..!! Thanks a lot..Can u clarify me how can i enter some data in each of the textfield in datatable and say submit,which has to be submitted to database

Answer (score 1):

If you do **not** want to fill it later you could use a plain html table instead:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Student Number</td><td>Student Name</td> ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td> ...
  </tr>
  <!-- 9 rows following -->
</table>
```

If you want to fill it later you have to use the `var` attribute of the dataTable and prepare a list with 10 (empty) elements in the backing bean:

```
<h:dataTable value=#{myBean.studentList} var="item">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Student Number" />
    </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{item.studNum}" />
  </h:column>
  ..
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I will fill it but on the page load, my page should display empty datatable with 10 rows

Comment: That's what the first snippet does. Adapt size of your cells with css or the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` attributes of the table tag.

Comment: Using plain html is fine but i want to use jsf tags...can u help me in that way

Comment: That's what the second snippet does. See also Grzegorz answer.

Comment: @Matt I am pretty sure `var=item` is not a correct syntax. Shouldn't it be replaced with `var="item"` or `var='item'`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Handy..it could resolve my problem...can u see my concern which I've posted in Grzegorz solution